# How to determine at runtime the accept type in a ServiceStack request

Tags: c#, json, xml, servicestack

I'm using ServiceStack to wrap a component that only returns xml or json (as string) and am wondering how I can differentiate in my service code whether to call the toJson() or toXml() methods of the 3rd party object?

The IRequest object exposes an AcceptTypes array that may contain  "application/json" or "application/xml" or "text/xml", is there a prefered way to make absolutely sure what format they are requesting and base my decision off of that?

Thank you,
Stephen

```
public partial class GenericServices
{
    public object Any(Generic request)
    {
        try
        {
            var response = new GenericResponse();

            var ruleAppRef = new CatalogRuleApplicationReference(Keys.ServiceEndpoint, request.RuleApp);
            using (var session = new RuleSession(ruleApplicationReference: ruleAppRef))
            {
                var entity = session.CreateEntity(request.EntityName, request.Data);
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(request.RulesetName))
                {
                    entity.ExecuteRuleSet(request.RulesetName);
                }
                else
                {
                    session.ApplyRules();
                }

                var reqTypes = Request.AcceptTypes;
                //todo: best way to determine formatter?
                if(reqTypes.Contains("application/json"))
                    response.Result = entity.GetJson();
                if (reqTypes.Contains("application/xml") || reqTypes.Contains("text/xml"))
                    response.Result =  entity.GetXml();
            }
            return response;
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            _log.Error("GenericServices", exception);
            throw;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ServiceStack calculates the most appropriate ResponseType to return and populates it in `IRequest.ResponseContentType`.

So you can determine it with:

```
response.Result = Request.ResponseContentType.MatchesContentType(MimeTypes.Xml)
    ? entity.GetXml()
    : entity.GetJson();
```